# C++ Err: 'Called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer'

Tags: c++, function, int

I am *attempting* to write a quadratic equation calculator in C++, and I keep running into this error. See if you can figure out why:
(the error occurs on the 'g =' line)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
    cout<<"Enter 'A' value:";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter'B' value:";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Enter 'C' value:";
    cin>>c;
    e = ((b * b) - (4 * (a*c)));
    d = sqrt(e);
    f = ((-b) + d) / (2 * a);
    g = ((-b) - d) / (2 * a);
    if(d > 0){
        cout<<"One solution is: "<<f<<endl;
        cout<<"The other solution is: "<< g <<endl;
    }
    else if(d == 0){
        cout<<"Your 1 solution is: "<< f <<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No real solutions!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should review the difference between *integer* division and *floating point* division.  Do you really want to use integer division?

Comment: BTW, the [square root function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) returns a floating point value, not an integer.

Comment: You need to return a value from `main`.  Try `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No, you don't. If control flows out of `main` without a `return` statement, `retun 0` is implied.

Comment: I get no compilation errors using `g++` version 4.9.2 on Cygwin for Windows 7.

Comment: @Angew:  I really don't like programs that use a lot of "implied" stuff.  The function was declared to return an integer, so it should.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/477971b844e486a5). I guess that in your real code, you forgot the `/` character.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "I think you should" is not nearly the same as "you need to."

Comment: Not reproducible. Notwithstanding the logical suggestions made in the answers below, none of them relate to the question, which does not actually contain the problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

The square root function will return floating point values, so you should use a floating point variable like double to store the result.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b,c,e;
    double d,f,g;
    cout<<"Enter 'A' value:";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter'B' value:";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Enter 'C' value:";
    cin>>c;
    e = ((b * b) - (4 * (a*c)));
    d = sqrt(e);
    f = ((-b) + d) / (2 * a);
    g = ((-b) - d) / (2 * a);
    if(d > 0){
        cout<<"One solution is: "<<f<<endl;
        cout<<"The other solution is: "<< g <<endl;
    }
    else if(d == 0){
        cout<<"Your 1 solution is: "<< f <<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No real solutions!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this code and the O.P's code?  Why did you post code without an explanation?

Comment: @Thomas I've added it.

Comment: While this may be correct, code alone isn't a good answer. Please include an explanation of what the problem was, and why this is the solution, so A) the OP understands the underlying logic and can fix this and similar issues himself, and B), other readers can understand the answer and apply it to their own similar (but not identical) problem.

Comment: Ah, okay, you got it. (It refreshed after I posted.)

Comment: I tried implementing the changes you suggested, but now the same error occurs on the 'e =' line.

Comment: The if-tests should be on variable 'e', not 'd', and the calculations of d, f, and g should not be made unless e>0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the square root function returns a floating point decimal, and you are trying to combine it with an integer. For example, 1 - 2.0. Both of the values have to be floating point decimals, so you should change "int" to "double" on line 5.